# SQL Query. I have this query that returns the % Difference between This weeks pay and Last weeks pay

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need it to remove the results that are less than 10% difference, as i only want to see the results that are over 10% Rise in pay. I have attached my result from my query.

[image: Here you can see the Results]

Now here is my code

```
SELECT *,
(tw.ThisWeeksPay - lw.LastWeeksPay) / NULLIF(lw.LastWeeksPay,0) * 100 AS 'PercentDifference'
FROM ThisWeek tw
INNER JOIN LastWeek lw ON lw.EeID = tw.EeID
ORDER BY tw.EeID, lw.EeID
```

Comment: in cases like this, you can simply query the query - wrap  it in parentheses, then AS SQ at the end of it, then SELECT * FROM in front of it, then adfer the whole lot WHERE SQ.PercentDifference >= 10.  so it could just be  SELECT * FROM (...) SQ WHERE SQ.PercentDifference >= 10

Comment: @MOKane - In the absence of a messaging system here : Why did you delete your other question?  It was missing some useful information, but I was in the middle of writing you a useful answer ;)

Comment: @MatBaillie Sorry. Im sort of new to StackOverflow and not exactly sure how to write questions to the professionals standards lol. The question didnt seem to be going down to well with everyone so i just removed it. Really appreciate you taking time to write a useful answer though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to refer to the value.  A simple way uses `apply`:

```
SELECT tw.*, lw.*, v.PercentDifference
FROM ThisWeek tw INNER JOIN
     LastWeek lw
     ON lw.EeID = tw.EeID CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ( (tw.ThisWeeksPay - lw.LastWeeksPay) * 100 / NULLIF(lw.LastWeeksPay, 0) )
     ) v(PercentDifference)
WHERE v.PercentDifference > 0.1
ORDER BY tw.EeID, lw.EeID;
```

You can also use the more traditional methods of a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Could i ask one more thing though? The people who were paid one week and not the other or not paid at all, is there a way to keep them in the report? I up voted your answer, but due to my Rep being low it doesnt change publicly. Thanks again

Comment: @MOKane . . . Use `FULL JOIN` and `OUTER APPLY` instead of `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: From a pedagogical standpoint, why not a simple `where` clause?

Comment: @BenThul . . . Because the `where` clause would need to repeat the expression.  The column alias would not be recognized.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. sorry to bother you again i still cant seem to get the people who were paid one week and not the other or not paid at all. The FULL JOIN and OUTER APPLY didnt work it just returned the same results. Would there possibly be another way? Thanks

Comment: @MOKane . . . .You should ask another question, and be clear about what you want.  This question asks specifically " i only want to see the results that are over 10% Rise in pay".  This implies that you need both weeks of pay -- which is what this answer does.